# get data on button click using jquery GET method

Tags: laravel

i have created ajax request as:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#gettype button').click(function(){
    var y = $(this).val();
   $.get("{{url('gettypes')}}",{id:y}, function(data){
    $('#samp').empty();
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {
              $('#samp').append("<option value='"+ element.ty_id +"'>" + element.ty_name + "</option>");
          });
    });
  });
 });
```

i want get data on button click in dropdown or table, my route is:

```
Route::get('gettypes',function(){
    $catid = Request::get('id');
    $typ = App\type::where('cat_id', $catid)->get();
    return Response::make($typ);
});
```

and my blade is:

```
  <table class="table"> 
    <tr id="gettype">
    @foreach($category as $val)
     <th><button class="btn btn-primary" value="{{$val->cat_id}}">{{$val->cat_name}}</button></th>
    @endforeach
   </tr>
  </table >
```

and

```
<select id="samp" class="form-control">
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

i am not getting is it not working on button click while it it wirking properly on dropdown change event, plz help. thanks

Comment: consider to accept/close the question

Answer (score 0):

You return view but need an json to iterate in foreach (jquery)
try this

```
Route::get('gettypes',function(){
    $catid = Request::get('id');
    $typ = App\type::where('cat_id', $catid)->get()->toArray(); //or toJson
    return response()->json($typ);
});
```

Comment: i just added e.preventDefault(); and it is working now, thanks